# make a disabled button look enabled

Tags: html, css

I have a button that is clicked and will display information next to it in a similar looking area.

I figured I'd just use another button to display it but make it disabled so it wouldn't actually be a button, but doing so makes the "button" faded out.

All I really need is a way to make a disabled button not look disabled. (ie, remove the faded appearance)

(It feels kind of hacky doing it this way, but it sort of works. I'm open to another way to do it.)
 Here is the code I'm using for this section:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Quick Roll</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt ng-cloak class="quick-rolls ng-cloak" ng-repeat-start="die in dice">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="quickRoll(die, $event)">{{"d" + die}}</button>
        </dt>
        <dd ng-cloak class="quick-rolls ng-cloak" ng-repeat-end>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" disabled>{{result}}</button>
        </dd>
      </dl>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you could have a "ghost" button, which doesn't function but acts as a fake "copy"-button that looks enabled, with the disabled real button hidden underneath.

Comment: If it's just to display information, why not a `<label>` or a `<span>`? You can apply any CSS class to it anyway.

Comment: well, I had originally tried a label or span, but the vertical alignment got screwed up cause they take up less vertical space than the buttons do, so I thought I'd just use a button since the spacing would match up correctly.  If there's a good way to match a span vertically to a button, that could work too

Comment: Being late and I'm tired, I may be missing something but, I'd be looking at adding height and line-height to match the button height and then "display: inline-block" to make a span take the same height as a button..
I usually add a 1px border and/or background-color to help with sizing, then remove them as necessary when done.

Comment: Sorry about the late response, got tied up in family stuff, but I think I eventually just followed what ErickPetru suggested and used a <label> inside an <h3> adjusting a whole slew of css elements and got it sort of kind of looking like what I wanted.